# Use SoapClient in ASP.Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-5, soap-client, .net-standard

In my .Net 5 Web API project i have all Controllers that must invoke an .asmx Soap Web Service.
To invoke the service i use a .Net Standard 2.0 Class Library where i have added a Service Reference with visual studio.

Everytime i have to call a Soap Service i create a new instance of ServiceSoapClient like

```
ServiceSoapClient myClient = new ServiceSoapClient();
```

Can i have the same issues as an HttpClient when is disposed ?
[(see this post by Nuno Caneco)](https://medium.com/@nuno.caneco/c-httpclient-should-not-be-disposed-or-should-it-45d2a8f568bc)

Can i use a static ServiceSoapClient like this ?

```
private static ServiceSoapClient myClient = new ServiceSoapClient();
```

maybe the ServiceSoapClient use an HttpClient under the hood.

Is it thread safe ?
This client will be used by all the different users that consume my API simultaneously.

Comment: `static` is not threadsafe

Comment: @viveknuna as i see HttpClient is threadsafe. If under the hood ServiceSoapClient uses HttpClient it will be threadsafe too.